# delete row from one table with condition from another table

Tags: sql-server

Here is my MS SQL Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RemoveFromCart
  @SellerID int
AS
DELETE FROM ShoppingCart
  WHERE Quantity > (SELECT Products.Quantity FROM Products, ShoppingCart
    WHERE ShoppingCart.ProductID = Products.ProductID )
  AND ShoppingCart.SellerID = @SellerID
```

I need to delete the row from `shoppingCart` where `ShoppingCart.Quantity` is bigger the the quantity of the product in `Products` table, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RemoveFromCart
    @SellerID int
AS

    DELETE 
        cart

    FROM 
        ShoppingCart cart
    INNER JOIN Products prod
        ON cart.ProductID = prod.ProductID

    WHERE 
            cart.Quantity > prod.Quantity
        AND cart.SellerID = @SellerID;
```

You can test it like this:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, Quantity, SellerID
INTO ShoppingCart
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS ProductID, 10 AS Quantity, 1 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ProductID,  6 AS Quantity, 1 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ProductID,  8 AS Quantity, 2 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ProductID,  6 AS Quantity, 2 AS SellerId 
) X;

SELECT 
    ProductID, Quantity, SellerID
INTO Products
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS ProductID,  9 AS Quantity, 1 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ProductID,  8 AS Quantity, 1 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ProductID,  7 AS Quantity, 2 AS SellerId UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ProductID,  6 AS Quantity, 2 AS SellerId 
) X;



Begin tran

select * from ShoppingCart;
select * from Products;

execute dbo.RemoveFromCart 1

select * from ShoppingCart;
select * from Products;
rollback tran
```

here's the results:

[image]

Note that ProductID = 1 is removed for SellerID 1 as it's got 10 in the cart while the limit it 8 in the product table. But the over-limit remains for SellerId 2 as the proc only works for one SellerId at a time.